# How to capture a click on a href value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code in the backend, ie.

```
<div class="navi">
  <a class="" href="0"></a>
  <a class="" href="1"></a>
  <a class="" href="2"></a>
  <a class="" href="3"></a>
</div>
```

Apologies for the basic question but I would like to use jQuery to capture the user's click when they only click on the href value of "0"

Basically want to hide a div called "info" when the user clicks on the where the href="0"

Unsure how to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like this (though I don't think that's a valid `href`):

```
$("a[href=0]").click(function() {
  $("#info").hide();
});
```

A better approach, if possible, would be to give the `<a>` a better `href` that points to the `<div>`, like this:

```
<div class="navi">
  <a class="" href="#info"></a>
  <a class="" href="#info1"></a>
  <a class="" href="#info2"></a>
  <a class="" href="#info3"></a>
</div>
```

Then you can use a more generic click handler, relating to the corresponding `<div>` like this:

```
$(".navi a").click(function() {
  $(this.hash).toggle();
});
```

This would toggle `<div id="info">` when you clicked the `href="#info"` link, the same or the others...if your links all relate to divs, this is a much better way to go, and it degrades gracefully with javascript disabled.

Comment: I think you should `return false;` on that.. ;)

Comment: @Reigel - Currently it goes to that div's location in the page, if you didn't want to you could `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();`, but usually you *don't* want to, the way it is allows you to rig up this div showing if you hit F5 for example, or bookmarking, etc...hash navigation has many uses.  Remember if it's a hash link, you're not leaving the page.